# Passing Data between Delegate and ViewModel ObservableObjects

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, appdelegate, observableobject

I have an app built using SwiftUI that works with user location. Using online tutorials, I have come up with a class `LocationManager` that handles the request using the delegate method and has an attribute `@Published` that sets the location as soon as it receives it.

I also have a `ViewModel` that has a function `getData(location: CLLocation)` that will properly update my view after an async call to a different API.

My question is, what is the best way to connect the `LocationManager` with the `ViewModel`, so that as soon as the `LocationManager` gets the location using the delegate it automatically calls the `getData()` function with that value?

I've tried to come up with a few solutions on my own, such as passing a closure to the `LocationManager` to call `viewModel.getData()` when the delegate is updated, but I got an issue with the "closure capturing a mutating self parameter". Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code in question:

```
final class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
  
    override init() {
        super.init()
    
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.location = location
        }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published dataArray = [Model]()

    func getData(location: CLLocation) {
         // async api call
         // update dataArray for view in completion handler
    }
}

struct ShowData: View {
     // initialize LocationManager
     @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

     // initialize ViewModel
     @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

     var body: some View {
          // show dataArray
     }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need two ObservableObjects? Can the LocationManager not just act as the view model as well?

Comment: I thought about doing that too, but I need to reuse the LocationManager in a different context, and it seems like bad coding practice to make different copies of it for different views

Comment: Okay -- if that's true, then I'd have the LocationManager owned by (ie a property on) the View Model. Then, you can use Combine to listen to the `@Published` values from the LocationManager and set the local `@Published` properties on the view model.

Comment: Note that you very well may not need a view model --  it's good in SwiftUI to consider whether you really need one.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying to just initialize LocationManager as part of the ViewModel? I guess this is probably the most straight forward way to do it, do you mind making an answer? (Also, the ViewModel I posted is very barebones, my actual one is much more complicated so it is necessary for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can own the LocationManager in your view model:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published dataArray = [Model]()

    var lm = LocationManager()
}
```

Then, you could architect the LocationManager to take a separate delegate (which could be the view model), or, you could use Combine to listen for changes on the `@Published` property on the `LocationManager`:

```
cancellable = lm.$location.sink { ... }
```